# Use a shortcode to display custom meta box contents

Tags: functions, customization, metabox, shortcode

Is this possible? If so, can someone point me towards a clear tutorial? I have a column of content I want to float right of the_content, so I'd like to be able to use a shortcode to put that content in the post for a page.

I've found the following (but want to modify it for get_post_meta):

```
function get_custom_field_fn() {    
 global $post; 
 $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cf_name', true); 
 return $custom_field_value; 
} 

add_shortcode('cf_name', 'get_custom_field_fn');
```

I'm guessing that I need to change a few things but not sure which things to change. My custom meta boxes will have 8 fields. I'm also guessing that my shortcode will need to allow for the post/page ID and I also need to interject some HTML in the function.

Comment: Can you clarify what problems you're having? Your example code looks correct... are you just having a hard time customizing it with the custom fields you want to use? Or are you trying to remove the whole function from the content so it can be displayed in a sidebar?

Comment: My main issue is how to change the code so I can use it with get_post_meta and how to include HTML in the function itself. Make more sense? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, the question is a bit unclear.  but i think you need shortcode attributes

```
function get_custom_field_fn( $atts) {    
global $post; 

 extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'meta' => ''
    ), $atts ) );


 $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, $meta, true); 
 return $custom_field_value; 
} 

add_shortcode('cf_name', 'get_custom_field_fn');
```

see the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Attributes

Comment: Yes. This is the solution.